# Fade-in JavaScript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following lines of code in my web page - [demo/example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJLENZ?editors=101).

**HTML:**

```
<button class="wrong-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">42</button>
<button class="right-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">43</button>

<p id="answer"></p>
```

**JS:**

```
function showResult(b) {
    var res = document.getElementById('answer');

    if (b.classList.contains('right-answer')) {
        res.innerHTML = '<span class="right">right</span>';
    } 

    else {
        res.innerHTML = '<span class="wrong">wrong</span>';
    }
}
```

How can I make the `<span>` tags appear or fade-in (with a duration of 2 seconds) when one of the buttons is selected, display this result (for a duration of 5 seconds) then if possible, removing it again (a duration of 2 seconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is another solution with vanilla JS and CSS3. I haven't put in unnecessary details about the code as it's straightforward.

```js
function showResult(b) {
  var res = document.getElementById('answer');
  if (b.classList.contains('right-answer')) {
    res.innerHTML = '<span class="right">right</span>';
  } else {
    res.innerHTML = '<span class="wrong">wrong</span>';
  }

  res.classList.remove("hidden");
  res.classList.add("visible");
  setTimeout(function() {
   res.classList.add("hidden");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<button class="wrong-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">42</button>
<button class="right-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">43</button>
<p id="answer" class="hidden"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wpqh0gx/3/). I added jQuery in my solution for easier coding, but you can do the same logic without it.

HTML:

```
<button data-answer="wrong">42</button>
<button data-answer="right">43</button>

<p id="answer">
    <span class="wrong">wrong</span>
    <span class="right">right</span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
p#answer span {display:none;}
```

JS

```
var timeout = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('p#answer span').hide();
    $('p#answer span.' + $(this).data('answer')).fadeIn(2000);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){$('p#answer span').fadeOut()},7000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jquery:

```
function showResult(b) {
    var res = document.getElementById('answer');

    if (b.classList.contains('right-answer')) {
        res.innerHTML = '<span class="right">right</span>';
        $("#answer").fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(3000);        
    } 
    else {
     res.innerHTML = '<span class="wrong">wrong</span>';
        $("#answer").fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(5000);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same thing done but using CSS classes more than JS/jQuery transitions:
https://jsfiddle.net/x2fgbjbq/

The key thing in this example is:

`transition: opacity 2s;`

I've also changed how the code uses the `<span>`. This is just personal preference - I try not to add/remove DOM elements on the fly if I can help it and instead just use what's already been created.